# Open windows in specific regions of the Screen

Tags: r

i'm developing an program in r that opens multiple windows.  I am getting tired of moving the windows to their positions on my windows desktop.  Is there a way to specify where to open the windows?

Comment: What type of windows are you opening? How are you opening them? What R GUI are you running? What OS are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `windows()` function has arguments `xpos` and `ypos` that allow you to specify its location, see `?windows` for details.

For example:

`for (i in 1:5)
  windows(1, 1, xpos=i*20, ypos=i*20)`

Comment: Is there a way to find the location of an open window?

Comment: @MadmanLee You'll be more likely to get an answer if you post that as a new question, perhaps linking to this one.